# Selecting certain results using CONCAT and INNER JOIN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join, concatenation

I'm trying a return a result of the full name of crew members that work on the ship USS Cochrane. I've already made sure that there are some crew members that work on the ship and my code is returning an empty set. Sorry I'm still trying to figure out how to display this code as mysql on here.

```
SELECT CONCAT(lastName,"",firstName) AS full_name
FROM crewmember INNER JOIN
     vessel
     ON crewmember.serialNumber = vessel.callsign
WHERE vessel.name = 'USS Cochrane';
```

Comment: Either your `where` clause or `on` clause are finding no matches.

Comment: Your Query is Ok..Check it is without where Clause..after that if you have no data their has a error on your JOIN clause..That is mean ON crewmember.serialNumber = vessel.callsign...After those edition's you can not get result..So there should be a error on Query..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following query.

The query will work only if the value of `serialNumber` in *crewmember* table matches the value from `callsign` in *vessel* table

```
SELECT CONCAT(lastName,' ',firstName) AS full_name
FROM crewmember cc JOIN vessel vv
WHERE cc.serialNumber = vv.callsign
AND vv.name = 'USS Cochrane';
```